Entire functions and Bergman spaces
Given an open set $D \subset \mathbb{C}$ with compact closure, let us consider the Bergman space $A^2(D)$ of all holomorphic functions on $D$ that are square integrable on $D$ with respect to the usual Euclidean area. It is well-known that $A^2(D)$ is a Hilbert space when
provided with the $L_2$ norm. The space of functions that are holomophic over the whole of $\mathbb{C}$ is a subspace of $A^2(D)$. What is its closure?

Carleman (1922) proved that, for $D$ a Jordan domain, polynomials are dense in $A^2(D)$. Markushevich and Farrell (1934) extended (independently) the result to bounded Caratheodory domains.

It is probably $A(D^)$, where $D^$ is the union of $D$ with all bounded components of the complement of $D$. I think this is not difficult to prove.

Would that work for an annulus?
